# Can't connect to localhost using Python's MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

When I run the following script:

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = 'localhost',
   user = 'erin',
   passwd = 'erin',
          db = 'sec')
```

I get the error:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")
```

There is no file called mysql.sock in that directory but I don't know what a socket is or how to specify the correct location for it using the MySQLdb module.

Comment: You could save more time if noticed error code (2) in the error message. 2 means file not found:

# perror 2
OS error code   2:  No such file or directory

Answer (score 44):

I've managed to solve this by setting my host to "127.0.0.1" rather than "localhost".

Comment: This works because when you specify `localhost`, it tries to connect through unix sockets, whereas when you connect through `127.0.0.1` it tries to connect through standard TCP/IP. However, if you specify `localhost`, then it will use the default `/tmp/mysql.sock` unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: I tested and find that "localhost" would be faster rather than "127.0.0.1" because "localhost" use local unix_socket. so I prefer roman answer.

Answer (score 27):

if your mysql socket is not placed in /tmp/mysql.sock, you can specify it with

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect (unix_socket = 'path_to_your_socket', host = 'localhost', user = 'erin', passwd = 'erin', db = 'sec')
```

edit: for mamp on macosx the mysql socket path should be something like `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: using `mysql_config --socket` in your shell should do, or /path/to/mysql/bin/mysql_config if you installed it in /opt or something

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not supposed to ask follow up questions - just ignore me if it's bad etiquette. When I type mysql_config --socket the response is '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Comment: is your mysql server actually running?

Comment: yes. I'm using MAMP. I can do stuff to the database through phpmyadmin.

Comment: ahh, mamp is special as it has a self contained mysql installation - see the addition to the comment above

Comment: if you are using MAMP most likely you will find the sock file here /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock good luck

Comment: And if you are using lampp it's in: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: I'm running XAMPP, and I found the socket file by running ps -A | grep msyql. This shows the command used by XAMPP to launch MySQL, which includes an argument to --socket. (On a Mac, it's `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock`)

Answer (score 5):

Your mysql installation probably put the socket somewhere else.  You can configure this in your mysql conf files.

You might want to check out this similar post: [Installing mysql on leopard: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136808/installing-mysql-on-leopard-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket)