# MySQLdb cannot resolve localhost

Tags: python, mysql, localhost, mysql-python

I have set up a basic transactional database using MySQL. Using python/MySQLdb, this works fine:

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect (host = "127.0.0.1", port = 3306, user = "root", passwd = "password", db = "test")
```

but this doesn't:

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", port = 3306, user = "root", passwd = "password", db = "test")
```

Using the latter generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "path\to\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "path\to\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

I have to admit I'm a bit confused as to why MySQLdb fails to resolve localhost. The C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file hasn't been modified in way. Using a regular Windows command prompt, `ping localhost` and `telnet localhost 3306` both work fine.

Environment:

- Windows 7 (64 bits)
- Python 2.7.2 (32 bits)
- MySQLdb 1.2.3
- MySQL 5.5.28 (64 bits)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662364/cant-connect-to-localhost-using-pythons-mysqldb

Comment: @RaunakAgarwal His problem was resolved by restoring his hosts file. However, mine hasn't been modified!

Comment: Your hosts file hasn't been modified, but does it include a line like         127.0.0.1       localhost  Uncommenting that line fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

From MySQLdb [docs](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html), about using `localhost`:

> This creates a connection to the MySQL server running on the local
>   machine via a UNIX socket.  UNIX sockets and named pipes don't work
>   over a network, so if you specify a host other than localhost, TCP
>   will be used, and you can specify an odd port if you need to.

Your server probably listen on TCP socket.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers my question. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an IPv6 issue. If so, it can be solved via

http://www.victor-ratajczyk.com/post/2012/02/25/mysql-fails-to-resolve-localhost-disable-ipv6-on-windows.aspx