# MySQL Server does not start on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mysql, linux, raspberry-pi

I am working with a Raspberry Pi running Debian Linux. I am trying to install  MySQL Server and run it and here is what I have done:

```
# sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql
```

No errors. Now I rebooted the system, then when starting up I get:

```
[FAIL] startpar: service(s) returned failure: mysql ... failed!
```

And I tried

```
# sudo service mysql start
mysql: unrecognized service
```

Lastly I tried

```
# /etc/init.d; mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I find that I have no folder named mysqld `in /var/run`. But I read that the sock file here shall be created the first time the server is created?

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Create the folder and make sure that it is writable by the mysql user

Comment: Look in /etc/init.d to see what the start/stop script is called. Might be 'mysqld'.

Comment: .. and look in /var/log/syslog and where ever the mysql log is to see why it failed.

Comment: I've made a test installation on my raspy. It worked out of the box. Which raspbian version are you using?

Comment: I am running debian version 3.2.27.
The start/stop script is 'mysql'.
I made the directory but still need a .sock file there too make mysql happy. Checking the systemlog seem not to help anything as it doesn't change when i try too run the server :p

Comment: which version of Pi are you using A or B? I have a B board and installed php, mysql, phpmyadmin, perl, libssl-dev, bugzilla and everything appears to be systems go.  Bugzilla is definitely a major hog (10 second requests, OCed to Medium using raspi-config) but for serving up the sites I'm putting together it runs like a champ.

Comment: To give some context on why A or B might matter; when doing the install I read something saying less than 256MB of RAM for running mysql can cause these socket errors.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your mysql server is not started. I usually run the stop command and then start it again:

```
mysqld stop
mysql.server start
```

Same error, and this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
/etc/init.d; mysql
```

The *usual* way to start the mysql server would be

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

The reason it's failing should be written to the logs (usually /var/log/mysqld.log) - what do the logs say?

Answer (score 0):

look into /var/log/mysql/error.log