# error during syncdb django python

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am getting an error when I am trying to do a 
python manage.py syncdb.

The error is as shown below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 231, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 103, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 411, in get_server_version
    self.cursor()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 306, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 387, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary MAC OS Snow Leopard

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136808/installing-mysql-on-leopard-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket

Comment: Your server might not be started. check if it's up with `ps aux | grep mysql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your debug messages more careful.
Error is "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket". U should check your connection params at settings.py

Answer (score 0):

The default path to MySQL socket doesn't work on MacOS X.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136808/installing-mysql-on-leopard-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket) provides a good answer to that problem, along with some handy links for further reading.